# Inno Setup remove/hide (not just disable) the Back button on a Wizard Page

Tags: inno-setup

I am aware that it is possible to disable (so it appears dimmed) the Back button on a Wizard Page using the following code:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
//Define whether the Back button is enabled
  if CurPageID = UnlockCodePage.ID then
    begin
      WizardForm.BackButton.Enabled := False;
    end;
end;
```

However, is there a way to actually completely remove/hide the Back button so that it can't be seen at all?

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat! If you submit that as an answer, I can then accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Button.Visible` property:

```
if CurPageID = UnlockCodePage.ID then
  WizardForm.BackButton.Visible := False;
```